# How to auto login using OAuth2.0 in Linkedin and fetch the organisation data in PHP?

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to implement the concept to take the organisation information from Linkedin. Before that I need to pass User Authentication & App Authorization from browser. I want to create it as a API that fetches data without any browser activities.

First Trigger, it will go to linkedin login page and ask permission to access the app

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&state=xxxxxx&scope=r_liteprofile&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

After login and authorization, it will redirect to a url and some code parameter will be retrieved

```
code = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Next trigger to get Access Token

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_id=xxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx
```

Retrieve Access Token

```
Access Token = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

After getting Access Token, it will be passed it to API Request

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations/xxxxxxx-H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

I'm newbie to this topic and I have searched maximum, unable to find out the proper guidance.

Thank you